# How stack text over an arrow

Tags: graphics, text, symbols

As part of a visualization of a mapping from a planar domain to another planar domain, I want to create a `Row` of the form `Row[{domain,mappingArrow,image}` where `domain` and `image` are graphics and `mappingArrow` is an arrow with text stacked above it.

The object `mappingArrow` should appear like this:

[image: labeled arrow]

(This was created in LaTeX with the `mathtools` package as `$\xrightarrow{ x \, \mapsto\ , f[x]}$`.)

How do I create this in *Mathematica* so I can insert it in that `Row`?

Comment: Maybe `DirectedEdge[X,Y,x:>f[x]]`. For example with X and Y circles: `DirectedEdge[Graphics[Circle[]],Graphics[Circle[]],x:>f[x]]`

Comment: @userrandrand: that does not give an arrow with a head on the right-hand end but rather an arrow with such head *and" a big dot on its left-hand end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try:

```
mappingArrow[text_] := Underscript[text, Style[RawBoxes@"\[RightArrow]", 20]]
```

For example:

```
mappingArrow[TraditionalForm[Function[x, f[x]]]]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use the same Latex in Mathematica?

```
<< MaTeX`
img = MaTeX["\\xrightarrow{x\\, \\mapsto \,f[x]}", Magnification -> 4];
Row[{domain, img, image}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

you can fill the domain and image as needed.

Comment: I'm going to be using this in a notebook for students not exposed to LaTeX, so I don't want to use actual LaTeX constructs there.